# Is it safe to disable or remove the Keyring in Ubuntu 18.04LTS since the last update broke it?

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome, software-uninstall, keyrings, gnome-keyring

After doing an update to my Ubuntu machine, the next time I re-started it asked for my keyring password. I put the correct one, an no matter how many time I do that upon every re-start it will ask me for the password again. Even when I do provide the correct password, my chrome and other apps do not safe password, and every time I have to re-sync my chrome. In addition, this started to create other odd behaviors.

I am all up for password managers and security, but this is not the first time that this happens to me. I experience something similar years ago. The problem is that every time that this happens I have to either re-install ubuntu or (this time) I had to create a new user account. But in the process I lost all the costumizations that I have done on my system (Many hours spend to make it cool) and I have to start all over from scratch.

With that in mind, since keying seems to be not too reliable, Is it safe to remove? If I remove it does that means that my Chrome will never remember the credentials to Sync on every startup?

I know it can be safely removed, but what are the consequences? that is what I don't yet understand.

Finally, if it is safe and no major side effects, what is the best way to remove the keyring for just one user (the main account that I use on a daily bases "Regular user NOT admin")?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

I removed `ubuntu-keyring` and `gnome-keyring` packages from my bionic installation. It broke my xserver. Trying to fix it now. Will update when it works.

So please do not remove the packages.